# between time validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am trying to create and test a validation that should appove wether a record can be saved or not depending on if it falls within a time range 8am - 9pm.

In my model I have

```
   validate :tour_times

  def tour_times
    if tour_time == Range.new(Time.local(tour_time.year, tour_time.month, tour_time.day, 8),Time.local(tour_time.year, tour_time.month, tour_time.day, 21, 00))
      binding.pry
    end
  end
```

In my test I have the following

```
    describe "invalid datetime" do 
      before do 
        @valid_1 = DateTime.new(2014, 10, 1, 7, 59)
      end

      it "should not accept times before 8am and after 9pm" do 
        expect(@form.update_attributes(tour_date: @valid_1.to_date, tour_time: @valid_1.to_time)).to be_falsey
      end
```

However it doesnt notice the validation, and start pry. It saves.

```
Failure/Error: expect(@form.update_attributes(tour_date: @valid_1.to_date, tour_time: @valid_1.to_time)).to be_falsey
       expected: falsey value
            got: true
```

Why is this. It should at least hit pry. weirdly though, I change the condition to unless and i hit pry with the tests that check for valid datetime.

Comment: What TimeZone do you have configured? Because 07:59 in UTC is after 8am in Berlin (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this

```
def tour_times
  if error_condition
    self.errors.add :field, 'Text of error'
  end
end
```

If you do not add a new error at validation method, then valid? returns true.

Iteration 1: I need to be sure that the code runs. Always render an error.

```
def tour_times
  self.errors.add :tour_date, 'with error'
end
```

Comment: why doesn't it hit binding.pry then?

Comment: they all fail doing that        Validation failed: Tour time Text of error

Comment: Please, test only this test: `it "should not accept times before 8am and after 9pm" do ...`